How to get an operating system's internal/keyboard charset, related to alt-key character input
Preface
I'm currently working on a small app that

literally types the input
from the system Clipboard (using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);),
by simulating the keystrokes of the keyboard (using java.awt.Robot.keyPress(keyCode)).

This is for some instances where UI elements do not support copy-paste (neither ctrl+v nor shift+ins), or deadkey control is blocked in the app or on the whole system.
It took me quite a while to find a simple solution: use the Alt-Key input method. (Essentially press Alt, enter the code, for example 0128 for €, then release Alt, badaa: you get €.
To get that code, I can simlpy convert the char to bytes (String.getBytes and new String(bytes)), but for both methods I need to specify the proper charset, because Java will try to use UTF-8, which does not always line up with the OS, especially in Windows (using cp1252).
This all works perfectly fine for all occasions I have encountered so far.
Problem
BUT: this method has one downside: I need to know the Operating System's keyboard charset/codepage.
Usually, under windows, it is the single-byte CP1252, but this will vary across countries and operating systems.
Question:
How to find out which charset/codepage the current operating system is sporting for keyboard input?
(Preferred answer related to Java, if possible.)
Hints
The following ways to retrieve the charsets are NOT viable, as they're only related to file I/O:

java.lang.System.getProperty("file.encoding")
java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()
java.io.FileReader.getEncoding() (which is just java.io.InputStreamReader.getEncoding() and usually just ends up calling java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset() anyways...)
JVM's command line parameter like java -Dfile.encoding=XXX app or client.encoding.override, but that would need to be adjusted manually, which is a task better not left to the user

I have found so far:

Windows PowerShell: [System.Text.Encoding]::Default, but that needs Windows and a PowerShell...
Do I have to go JNI and BOOL GetKeyboardLayoutName(LPTSTR pwszKLID); and hope I get this to match with Java's Charsets?


With Java 18+ you can do System.getProperty("native.encoding")

Why are you even concerned about charsets? You should only be concerned about keycodes. Keycodes are charset-independent. If you want to simulate keys that generate a specific non-ASCII character, then use the keystroke sequence that generates Unicode.

I'd love to do the Unicode input, but for Windows that needs an extra update of the registry. So this method doesn't work out-of-the-box, sadly. On the other hand, you're right, I risk the whole thing not working. So I'll go both ways: Check: if the RegKey is set, use Unicode input, else suggest installing prepared RegKey, else use the system above, and finally, let the user adjust the charset so that it fits the app, if deviating from the OS.

Wow. This was easier than expected.
Lots of thanx go to @Elliott Frisch: He gave me a really good idea.
Step 1: Idea
So I tested a few System.properties with this code:
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class CharsetInfo {



    static public final String[]    TESTS_JAVA      = { "java.version\t\t", "java.runtime.version\t", "sun.arch.data.model\t" };
    static public final String[]    TESTS_ENCODING  = { "file.encoding\t\t", "native.encoding\t\t", "sun.jnu.encoding\t", "sun.stdout.encoding\t", "sun.stderr.encoding\t" };



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");

        for (final String t : TESTS_JAVA) {
            System.out.println("\t" + t + "\t" + System.getProperty(t.trim()));
        }

        System.out.println("    ------------------------------------------");

        for (final String t : TESTS_ENCODING) {
            System.out.println("\t" + t + "\t" + System.getProperty(t.trim()));
        }
        System.out.println("\t" + "Charset.defaultCharset()\t" + Charset.defaultCharset());
        //      System.out.println("System.console().charset()                = " + System.console().charset()); // java 22/23/24/+

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}

(Taken from here and magled a bit)
Info on the last line (regarding System.console().charset()): This only compiled with 22+, and then System.console() always returned null. This is probably due to the way I launch java (in the next step), that Java realizes it's not inside an "interactive console" and thus has no console object instantiated. So: not useful in our scenario, as we need this to work in all contexts.
Step 2: Gathering data
I wrote a small app that

detects all installed full JDKs,
then compiles the given file CharsetInfo
then runs it with loads of output looking like this

Example output for Java 10:
D:\apps\java\jdk-10.0.2\bin
        Compiling:  D:\apps\java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\javac.exe D:\workspace\Test\src\CharsetInfo.java
        Success.


        Executing:  D:\apps\java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe -classpath D:\workspace\Test\src CharsetInfo
        Out:
----------------------------------------------------------
    java.version            10.0.2
    java.runtime.version        10.0.2+13
    sun.arch.data.model     64
    ------------------------------------------
    file.encoding           Cp1252
    native.encoding         null
    sun.jnu.encoding        Cp1252
    sun.stdout.encoding     null
    sun.stderr.encoding     null
    Charset.defaultCharset()    windows-1252
----------------------------------------------------------
        Success.

(I run all those JDKs on the same Windows Server 2016 for testing purposes)
Step 3: Statistics
Now I took all the outputs and dropped them into a table:

Step 4: Lessons Learned
As seen, sun.jnu.encoding seems to be present on all Java releases. I used Oracle JDK, OpenJDK, Zulu. (And it looks like I got rid of my GraalVMs some time in the past.)
But what we also see, is that from Java 17 on, native.encoding will also be present.
So, with sun. properties running out of style sooner or later, the primary focus is on native.encoding, followed by sun.jnu.encoding, followed by an exception if this code gets waayy too old.
Step 5: Put it into code
Of course, this will land in my library now:
static public Charset getSystemCharset() {
    try {
        final String csName = System.getProperty("native.encoding");
        if (csName != null && csName.trim().length() > 0) return Charset.forName(csName);
    } catch (final Exception e) { /* pass-thru */ }
    try {
        final String csName = System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding");
        if (csName != null && csName.trim().length() > 0) return Charset.forName(csName);
    } catch (final Exception e) { /* pass-thru */ }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not detect a realiable source for OS native encoding in System.getProperty()!");
}


This solution will use the system default encoding. This is not necessarily the encoding used by the application into which you are trying to enter the input. Each running application may choose to use a different encoding.
